# Using PyCharm Professional and Vagrant, how do I run a Django server?

Tags: python, django, vagrant, pycharm

I have set up already my configuration so that it will run the server remotely. When I click run, I see the command used:

```
ssh://vagrant@localhost:2222/usr/bin/python -u "C:/Users/MyName/ProjectName/config/manage.py" runserver localhost:8080
```

(I've replaced the directory names for anonymity reasons).

When I do run this, It fails (obviously) because it's using a windows path to my manage.py
Specifically the error I get is

```
`/usr/bin/python: can't open file 'C:/Users/MyName/judgeapps/config/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What I can't figure out after extensive googling, is how to force django to use a path on my vagrant machine. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The trick is creating a Python interpreter in PyCharm, and configuring the project to use this interpreter.

*Note: The following applies to PyCharm Professional 4.0.*

### Create a Python Interpreter for Vagrant

1. Start your Vagrant machine from PyCharm by navigating to `Tools->Vagrant->Up`
2. SSH into your Vagrant box: `Tools->Start SSH Session`. Select `Vagrant at [VagrantFolder]` from the list that appears.
3. From the terminal that appears, run `which python`. This will give you an absolute path to python on your virtual machine.
4. `File->Settings->Project->Project Interpreter`. Click the **+** button to create a new one.
5. Choose `Vagrant`. Your `Vagrant instance folder` should be the location of your VagrantFile on your host machine. `Python interpreter path` should be set to the absolute path you found in step 3 above.
6. Click **OK** to save. **Note:** Vagrant has to be `up` in order for this to work.

### Configure Your Project to Use the Correct Interpreter

1. From the `Run` menu, select `Edit Configurations`
2. Click **+** and add a new `Django Server`
3. Set your `Host` to `0.0.0.0`. This will bind the `runserver` command to an external IP.
4. Check `Run browser` and set the URL to the host/port you mapped to your VM in your VagrantFile (for example, if I map my host's port `8080` to Vagrant's `8000`, I'd use `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`)
5. Choose the `Python interpreter` that you set up in the above section from the `Python interpreter` dropdown
6. Add your absolute `path mappings` (this is sometimes optional, depending on where your VagrantFile is stored).
7. Click **OK** to save.

Run your project, and enjoy the glory that is Vagrant.

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason I can't actually access the path mappings tab. Any suggestions? Edit: I do have a remote interpreter set up as my default and chosen here.

Comment: Clicking on the `...` button doesn't pop up a new window? The input itself should be disabled, but there's a button to the right of it.

Comment: The Input is disabled, and clicking on the '...' does nothing. Shift + enter also fails.

Comment: Looking over your edited tutorial, I see that I didn't select vagrant as the option for my interpreter. I did this as I got a File not found exception for my private key (it's there, just not being found). Could this be the root of my problem?

Comment: That could definitely be the issue. If you `vagrant ssh` from PyCharm, do you get the same error?

Comment: Nope. If I use my ssh credentials anywhere else it works, same with my ppk.

Comment: I'm adding another comment here because it's more appropriate here that in the other thread. I still am getting the exception, and [here's an image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kx1Dh.jpg). Can you give me any help?