# In PyCharm 4 Professional, why can't i set path mappings?

Tags: python, pycharm

I recently posted a question which gave me the answer that I needed to set my path mappings. This currently doesn't work, and I can't figure out why. Clicking on the`...` doesn't open up anything, and the textbox is disabled. Could anyone suggest why it might not work? thanks.

Comment: A link to this question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27166855/3286955

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved by updating to Django 4.0.1 from Django 4.0