# django - run project from PyCharm server not accessible

Tags: django, server, pycharm

When I run my django server from PyCharm it is not accessible from the outside world.

I read that you can run in the cmd like that, and it works.

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

How do I run it to be accessible to the outside world from **PyCharm**?

I need to run it from there is order to debug.

thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using PyCharm Professional and Vagrant, how do I run a Django server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27166855/using-pycharm-professional-and-vagrant-how-do-i-run-a-django-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the upper-right corner (by default) of PyCharm you can edit the configuration for your server:

[image: PyCharm Edit Configuration for server]

In there specify as host `0.0.0.0`.

Don't forget to take care of your firewall/NAT by opening and forwarding the appropriate ports.