# How to serve HTML + JS + CSS webapp from my machine so that others can view it?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, pycharm

I'm a newbie developing a small web application that uses HTML, JavaScript (Angular 1.5.0) & CSS. I am using Grunt to process, jslint, minify my javascript and CSS files. This front-end communicates via HTTP Rest calls to a Django application that is also running locally (which has its own database)

This webapp currently lives only on my laptop (MacBook Pro) and I use the PyCharm IDE to edit the files. When I want to test out the app, I simply go to http://localhost:63342/myapp/index.html#. PyCharm's built-in webserver serves it up for me and I can play with it there.

However, I want to allow a select few people to also access the webapp from other locations on the internet. When they try to access http://***MyPublicIpAddress***:63342/myapp/index.html, they get connection denied.

What is the quickest/easiest/simplest way I can share my webapp with those other people? I do not know much about setting up and configuring Webservers, so if you can give me the simple/easy instructions (or point me to a doc!) that would be most appreciated.

I posted this question to the PyCharm community forum [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206634179-How-can-I-get-built-in-WebServer-to-be-accessible-by-others-on-my-network-), but got no response.

**Edit**
Many answers say I need hosting service. Yes, If I want to deploy my website to a fixed IP address. But is there no way to simply allow them to briefly visit my webapp while temporarily running a toy web-server on my laptop? This is not a long-term solution I understand. But just to give them a peek. If possible I would like to avoid the effort and learning-curve involved in pushing it to a hosting service. I would have to setup the back-end API, database, etc (which are all currently running locally)

Comment: What about using localtunnel ? https://localtunnel.me/

Comment: Your question in the PyCharm forum said "local network". But your question here says "on the Internet". The latter opens up a bunch of networking issues that are independent of PyCharm and Python, involving either your router or something like localtunnel. It's a hard topic, but that's a good thing...you really don't want the outside world to easily get to your computer.

Answer (score 3):

There's many services that allow you to host your project online.

**For small projects**
[CodePen](http://codepen.io/): http://codepen.io/
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/): http://plnkr.co/
[kodeWeave](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/): http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/

**For large projects**
[Cloud9IDE](https://c9.io/): https://c9.io/
[Koding](http://koding.com/): http://koding.com/
[Github](https://pages.github.com/): https://pages.github.com/
[Sourceforge](https://pages.github.com/): https://sourceforge.net/
[Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/): https://www.heroku.com/

**BTW**: [kodeWeave](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/) is my project. It uses [Github Gists](http://gist.github.com/) to save and retrieve your weaves online, thus is not actually saved on the site plus it's a very reliable host when it comes to small projects like it is. (Inspiration from [Dabblet](http://dabblet.com/).)

It's being made kind of as a JSFiddle alternative for mobile devices, except without all the http requests.

It has many libraries built in (Such as [JQuery](http://jquery.com/), [Angular](https://angularjs.org/), [Font Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/), etc:) in addition when you export as a zip file you will get all those libraries (Hence the `except without all the http requests` comment). You can also export your weave as a Windows, Linux, Mac, Chrome Application, and/or as a Chrome popup extension.

[You can watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZLlx2KfPD8) I made that explains how to use [kodeWeave](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/) for desktop exportation.

I've listed services I use and recommend. I will not list something I haven't tried without warning.

If you have a spare laptop you can [use that as a web server](http://www.instructables.com/id/Turn-an-old-Computer-into-a-web-server/). I've never done it myself because it's not worth the this for me. However something you may want to look into

Lastly you can read [Creating a Local Server Configuration with PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/creating-a-local-server-configuration.html) which maybe the option you're looking for.

Comment: I will definitely lookup kodeWeave. Thanks!

Many answers say I need hosting service. Yes, If I want to deploy my website to a fixed IP address. But is there no way to simply allow them to briefly visit my webapp while temporarily running a toy web-server on my laptop? This is not a long-term solution I understand. But just to give them a peek. If possible I would like to avoid the effort and learning-curve involved in pushing it to a hosting service. I would have to setup the back-end API, database, etc (which are all currently running locally)

Comment: You can read [Creating a Local Server Configuration with PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/creating-a-local-server-configuration.html) which maybe the option you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use localtunnel to expose your localhost- https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel

Comment: oooooo and it's under the [MIT](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) license. I like this!

Answer (score 1):

You need hosting, or try codepen.io for small project.

Comment: Many answers say I need hosting service. Yes, If I want to deploy my website to a fixed IP address. But is there no way to simply allow them to briefly visit my webapp while temporarily running a toy web-server on my laptop? This is not a long-term solution I understand. But just to give them a peek. If possible I would like to avoid the effort and learning-curve involved in pushing it to a hosting service. I would have to setup the back-end API, database, etc (which are all currently running locally)

Answer (score 1):

Change the configuration in PyCharm to host at `0.0.0.0`. You will also need to port forward your router... I would strongly suggest not using this as any sort of long, medium or short term solution.

Comment: How can I change that configuration in PyCharm? I just want to do it for a few seconds.

Many answers say I need hosting service. Yes, If I want to deploy my website to a fixed IP address. But is there no way to simply allow them to briefly visit my webapp while temporarily running a toy web-server on my laptop? This is not a long-term solution I understand. But just to give them a peek. If possible I would like to avoid the effort and learning-curve involved in pushing it to a hosting service. I would have to setup the back-end API, database, etc (which are all currently running locally)

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422421/django-run-project-from-pycharm-server-not-accessible) will help.